# Another HTML5 time element question

Tags: html

What does the following text mean below in layman's terms. If you can give me another example of machine-readable?

`This element is intended as a way to encode modern dates and times in a machine-readable way so that, for example, user agents can offer to add birthday reminders or scheduled events to the user's calendar`

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at an example without the `time` element.

```
<html>
<head><title>Date of Birth</title></head>
<body>
Joe was born on 20 Jan 1985.
</body>
</html>
```

If you were writing a program to parse this HTML page, it would not be very easy to extract the date of birth. How will your program (i.e. a machine) know that "20 Jan 1985" is a date of birth? Humans do, because of the context surrounding the date.

Now consider this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Date of Birth</title></head>
<body>
Joe was born on <time datetime="1985-01-20">20 Jan 1985</time>.
</body>
</html>
```

Your program can now extract the date of birth quite easily simply by getting the `time` element's `datetime` attribute. The `time` element makes it easier to identify dates and times. For example, a browser (i.e. a machine) could detect this date and offer to add it to your calendar.